# IEqualityComparer equivalent to (=) operator

Tags: f#, equality

Is an `IEqualityComparer` exposed that has the same behavior as the equality (`=`) operator? The LanguagePrimitives module contains a few: `FastGenericEqualityComparer`, `GenericEqualityComparer`, `GenericEqualityERComparer`. Maybe there are others as well?

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly that you want an equality comparer that would call `Equals` on value types and `ReferenceEquals` on ref types?

Comment: @Dan: I want the same behavior as the equality operator, essentially, structural equality.

Comment: `==` operator behavior is what I described above. It checks structural equality for value types only. Also, would you consider converting your edit into an answer? You can mark it as correct later so the question doesn't turn up on “Unanswered” lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging through Reflector a bit more, it looks like [`FastGenericEqualityComparer`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-languageprimitives.html#FastGenericEqualityComparer) is the one. It and the ([`=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340212.aspx)) operator both call [`HashCompare.GenericEqualityIntrinsic<'T>`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-languageprimitives-hashcompare.html#GenericEqualityIntrinsic).

#### EDIT

[`HashIdentity.Structural`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-hashidentity.html#Structural) also forwards to `HashCompare.GenericEqualityIntrinsic`.